# Get belongsTo ID without fetching record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to fetch the belongsTo ID without fetching the actual record. My JSON API returns the ID for the belongsTo relation.

**I have the following models**

```
App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend(
  title: DS.attr()
  ingredients: DS.hasMany('ingredient', async: true)
)

App.Ingredient = DS.Model.extend(
  recipe: DS.belongsTo('recipe')
  product: DS.belongsTo('product', async: true)
)

App.Product = DS.Model.extend(
  title: DS.attr()
)
```

**This is my route:**

```
App.RecipeIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: (args) ->
    @store.find('recipe', args.recipe_id)
)
```

**This is my controller:**

I'm trying to find the product id within this controller.

```
App.RecipeIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  hasRecipeInCart: null

  actions:
    toggleCart: ->
      @content.get('ingredients').then((ingredients) =>
        # how do I get product id here, without lookup up the product relation?
        # this 'get' makes Ember call: /api/v1/products/1
        # I simply want the product ID (in this case 1), without having to call the server again.
        ingredient.get('product').then((product) =>
          product.id # => 1
        )
```

**My JSON looks like this:**

HTTP GET: /api/v1/recipes/1

```
{
  "recipe": {
    "id":1,
    "title":"Recipe 1",
    "ingredients":[2,1]
  }
}
```

HTTP GET: /api/v1/ingredients?ids[]=2&ids[]=1

```
{
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id":2,
      "recipe":1,
      "product":1
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "recipe":1,
      "product":2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is now much easier with the ds-reference feature that was added to ember data. You can now do:

```
var authorId = post.belongsTo("author").id();
```

See http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code

Comment: If you want to get the id in a template, you need to write your own helper: [Ember Data issue #4407](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4407)

Answer (score 6):

A ton of work is going into redoing the relationships, you can pull it out of the underlying properties from the data attribute `model.get('data.product.id')`

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/16/edit

Comment: That also triggers a call to the server: /api/v1/products/1, for some reason. I used this code: @content.get('ingredients').then((ingredients) =>
          ingredients.forEach((ingredient, index, enumerable) =>
            productId = ingredient.toJSON().product # this line triggers the call to the server.

Comment: That's a ugly implementation in ED, i might need to do a PR or find out why it's fetching the models for json.

Comment: It's possible to get the product id like this:
ingredient.get('data').product.id
or
ingredient._data.product.id

Comment: This nolonger works in Ember 2. How do I get belongsTo id without fetching record in newer versions of Ember (and Ember data)?

Comment: @Kingpin2k did you ever open anything against Ed about this?

Comment: There is an easier solution nowadays: http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code  You can do something like: var authorId = post.belongsTo("author").id();

Answer (score 6):

For ED 2.x, relationships have been reworked and were broken for getting underlying data [until the `ds-references` feature landed](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/12/ember-data-2-3-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code).

To do this in ED 2.4+, you need to use the new `belongsTo` method to work with underlying data.

To get an id for a belongsTo ref:

```
var id = this.get('model').belongsTo('myBelongsToKey').value();
```

Comment: ds-references has landed :) http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code