# Prevent Ember from fetching related model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `device` model, which has one (`belongsTo`) an `ingest` model.

Elsewhere in my app, I have a `device` loaded, and need to know if the device has an `ingest` present on it. I check it like this:

```
return this.get('device.ingest') === null;
```

By calling `device.ingest`, Ember automatically issues an AJAX request to `.find('ingest', device.ingest.id)`. I really just want to know if it's there or not, I don't want to fetch it.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get belongsTo ID without fetching record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479179/get-belongsto-id-without-fetching-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't this simply work for you?

```
return this.get('device.data.ingest.id') === null /* or undefined */;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, but you could access to private property of the model:
`this.get('device')._data.ingest === undefined`
or `this.get('device')._data.ingest_id === undefined` (depends of your naming system).