# Searching Ember data async hasMany ids without loading all the id records

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to search through several thousand records for a particular record. I have loaded a User model and it has several thousand Shipments that are async. In other words I have the serializer send down `shipment_ids` with the user model.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  shipments: DS.hasMany('shipment', { async: true })
});
```

I want to search through all those ids to see if a particular record's id is among them. However I don't want to go to the api and load each and every single record. I just want to be able to search through the `shipment_ids`.

[I have a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wofig/1/) that showcases it loading all the records. How do I change this so it doesn't make any api calls for a shipment and still finds the specific record?

Instead of doing

```
this.get('shipments').any(function(shipment){
  return shipment.get('id') === "10124";
```

there has to be a way to go through only the ids, no?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution described in "[Get belongsTo ID without fetching record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479179/get-belongsto-id-without-fetching-record)"
 seems to work as of Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.10.  Briefly, you can do the following to access the underlying

```
modelInstance.get('data.belongsToRelation.id');
```

Presumably you can also do this (though I have not tested it):

```
modelInstance.get('data.hasManyRelation');
```

Original Answer (**DO NOT USE**):

> I have accomplished this on a belongsTo by adding a second model field for the id.  My example:
>
> App.User = DS.Model.extend({
>        group: DS.belongsTo('group', { async: true }),
>        groupId: DS.attr('number')
>      });
>
> So maybe you can do this?
>
> App.User = DS.Model.extend({
>       shipments: DS.hasMany('shipment', { async: true }),
>       shipmentIds: DS.attr('array')
>     });
>
> You will need to add an array transform in app/transforms/array.js (assuming you use ember-cli)
>
> import DS from 'ember-data';
>
> var ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
>         deserialize: function(serialized) {
>             return serialized;
>         },
>         serialize: function(deserialized) {
>             return deserialized;
>         }
>     });
>
> export default ArrayTransform;
>
> Let me know if it works as I probably will need to something similar in my app soon.

Comment: This indeed does work. I never thought to capture the ids from the json like that. [http://jsbin.com/wofig/3/](http://jsbin.com/wofig/3/) You can also leave out the array transform and Ember will guess it is an array. [http://jsbin.com/wofig/4/](http://jsbin.com/wofig/4/) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I just realized that my approach causes some serious bugs for belongsTo. Basically once you add the `groupId`: DS.attr('number') property it will mess up the normalization process and break the async lookup of the belongs to relationship.  I'll see if I can think of a work around but in the meantime be warned.

Comment: So your update is essentially doing what my original answer was. :]

Comment: mmmm @bfcoder there is a difference - your answer uses `_data` instead of `data`.

Comment: @leejt489 While you are correct, it is still the same data. It is just accessed in a different way.

Comment: @bfcoder yeah sorry to disappoint.  Depending on the serializer you are using the original hack I wrote will work - but be careful because it caused me a ton of headaches

Answer (score 2):

This hack is very smelly but it's the only way I have found. And it is to search with `_data`

```
this.get('content._data.shipments').any(function(shipment){
  return shipment.get('id') === "10124";
});
```

It won't make any api calls. But there has to be a more acceptable method that won't be prone to breakage when updating Ember.

[Here is an updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wofig/2/) to show this. Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Ember Data 2.3 you can use this code:

```
// get all ids without triggering a request
var commentIds = post.hasMany('comments').ids();
```

See http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/12/ember-data-2-3-released.html for details.

Comment: No you cannot, you can do that starting from Ember Data 2.5.x+